# Registering custom Translator Loader in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-translate

I'm trying to register a custom database translator loader.

For that i was inspired by:
[Feeding Zend Translator](http://www.dasprids.de/blog/2012/08/23/feeding-zend-i18n-translator-from-a-database)

I have the following facotry code in (module.config.php):

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'translator' => function($sm){
            $translator = new \V1\Service\DatabaseTranslationService();
            return $translator->createService($sm);
        },
    ),
),
```

The DatabaseTranslationService looks like that:

```
$config = $serviceLocator->get('Config');
    $trConfig = isset($config['translator']) ? $config['translator'] : array();
    $translator = new \Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator();
    $translator->getPluginManager()->setInvokableClass('database', '\Foo\I18n\Translator\Loader\DatabaseTranslator', true);
    $translator->addTranslationFile('database', 'en_EN');

    return $translator;
```

But it seems like "setInvokableClass" isn't used:
I got this error:

```
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for database
```

Does anybody know how to registering the Translator correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After two days of search I've found a solution.

I don't know if it's a good solution, but it works for me.

Replace the line:

```
$translator->getPluginManager()->setInvokableClass('database', '\Foo\I18n\Translator\Loader\DatabaseTranslator', true);
```

with

```
$viewHelper = $serviceLocator->get('viewHelperManager');
$viewHelper->setInvokableClass('database', '\Foo\I18n\Translator\Loader\DatabaseTranslator', true);
```

I hope this solution helps you.

Answer (score 2):

In the current version (zf2 2.2.4) you only need to change the `type`-config entry:

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'de_DE',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'YourNamespace\I18n\Translator\Loader\YourCustomFormat',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.whatever',
        ),
    ),
)
```

The `YourNamespace\I18n\Translator\Loader\YourCustomFormat` must implement the `Zend\I18n\Translator\Loader\FileLoaderInterface` interface; the `load($locale, $filename)` method must return a `Zend\I18n\Translator\TextDomain` instance.

This worked for me.

(of course the autoloader must find the class)

Comment: When changing this, I recieve an error about the `base_dir` not being available.

Comment: Then remove the comment `//` characters ;)

Comment: Well yes, but why are they commented out in your answer?